# Left and right operator groups

Tags: group-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a set. D.J.S. Robinson, A Course in the Theory of Groups, Second Edition, 1996, p. 28-29, defines a "right" $\Omega$-group and adds : "The concept of a *left operator group* is defined in the obvious way."
Since it is not assumed that there is a structure on the set $\Omega$, I don't see the usefulness of a distinction between "right $\Omega$-group" and "left $\Omega$-group". Do you ? Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference, a small one, but there is. It is just notation. If the set $\Omega$ does not carry any structure, it is just notation, that is a left operator group is a map $\beta \colon \Omega\times G \to G$ with the "operator" written on the left. If $\Omega$ does not carry structure, there is no further difference. But the first example gives a hint:

- A ring $R$ and a left $R$-module $A$ form a left-operator group. Written "rightish" the compability condition would read 
  $$  (a^r)^s  = a^{sr} $$
  which is not quite nice to read. So it is good to have the leftish option at hand, writing 
  $$ {}^s({}^ra) = {}^{sr}a $$

So the short answer is: No difference, but having the possibility to write it on the left comes in quite handy sometimes.

Comment: Tthanks. It is probably the best possible answer, but I note that other authors (W.R. Scott, J.S. Rose, Bourbaki...) don't distinguish betwen left and right operator groups. Moreover, for Bourbaki, the external law of a left $R$-module structure on $M$ and the external law of a right $R$-module structure on $M$ are both maps  from $ R \times M$ into $M$.